# JQuery Remote API With HTTP Basic Authentication Header

Tags: jquery, ajax

We are tying to make a connection to the MYEMMA API which must include an HTTP Basic authentication header containing the public & private API keys for our account.

How do we include this information in our JQuery API call? Here is what we have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    url:  "https://api.e2ma.net/123/members/add",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST"
     {
       "fields": {
       "first_name": "Benjamin"
     },
     "email": "benjamin@myemma.com"
    }
  });
</script>
```

We just need to know how to create the authentication header, including our keys, to include in the call.

For reference: http://myemma.com/api-docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are currently doing is very far from what you should be doing (it looks like you are giving labels to lots of strings, etc, which cannot be comma separated, which will be an *invalid label* error).

As per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), add `username` and `password` keys to your `$.ajax()`.

```
$.ajax({
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    url:  'https://api.e2ma.net/123/members/add',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
       first_name: 'Benjamin',
       email: 'benjamin@myemma.com'
    }
});
```

You don't need to wait for the DOM to be ready to fire a XHR.

Comment: So by adding the username and password keys to the above call (or in my case, public and private keys), this in effect will create the necessary HTTP Basic authentication header that the remote API expects?

Comment: @user1113083: It should do. I've never used them before, but I've read about them. Check the documentation link in the answer for further information.

Comment: When I ran the snippet, here is what I received: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {". The line number referenced the open bracket immediately following the "POST".

Comment: Okay, the call successfully went through, only now we are getting: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.e2ma.net/1702425/members/add. Origin [my domain] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @user1113083: Sounds like you are being stopped by Same Origin Policy. It also sounds like CORS is not an option. You will need to proxy it via something that is immune to SOP, such as a server side script or YQL (or see if they have a JSONP API).